# Drawing parts of a Blob to html canvas without data urls in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, security-by-obscurity

I'm testing something out using a webapp where users can see a few pieces of an image but not all of it at once. The whole data is sent down to the client and decrypted client-side. That data is then in base64 so I simply use:

```
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imgdata;
```

In order to display it. Then I can call

```
my2Dcontext.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height)
```

and all would be good, right?

Except no, the original full data is incredibly easy to download. Just copy the data source from the image and then download or open inspector and download it that way.

For this reason I'm wondering how I could conceivably get the data from imgData onto the screen without having to put it *all* on the screen.

*Is there any way to render part of an image from data onto canvas without create things like full-image data urls?*

I know this is an odd case, but if any of you guys have any creative ideas I'd really appreciate it!

(P.S, I'm aware this is essentially security through obscurity in some sense and that if they can display the parts separately on the screen they can just patch them together. I'm just trying to stop the easiest level of extraction. Thanks)

Comment: Why not send partial data only?

Comment: @Teemu, The images are very large and the user can very rapidly view different segments of the image. I'd basically have to stream the image chunk as they click different regions of the image map. The bandwidth and server stress wouldn't work.

Comment: Hmm ... Originally load the image in chunks, and keep the chunks as base64 until the image really is needed. Not bullet proof, but lifts the fruit a bit higher.

Comment: That's... plausible. Is it possible to take base64 image data and convert that into data chunks in js? I'll do some more searching into this.

Comment: I suppose the image data can't just be chopped, but you can load data for images as you need, and create the actual images later.

Comment: So the question is one of the many *"how do I protect my content from being saved by the user?"* type, right? If so, the answer is as always, *You can't*. You could try whatever you want, you will not succeed. A lot of users don't even think about *right click -> save as*, and will just do a print screen. That's a lost cause. If you want protection, add a copyright notice on your page and sue them if they don't respect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot actually protect displayed images from a user determined to get the image. A simple screen grabber tool then can be used to patch together the tiles/parts of the image. An advanced user can inject a script to do the same automatically.

However, for the sake of creative approaches:

### Image Data Obfuscation

There is the option of obfuscating the data itself before delivery so that if any attempt is made to download the *source* it will be useless. When shown on canvas you can "decode" the data so it shows properly (but then referrer again back to screen grabber tool, the option user has to save the canvas as image and so forth).

Obfuscating doesn't have to be very complex though, you need to find an algorithm that can mess with the bitmap data for the source, and likewise a way to put it back in order - this will of course come with its own challenges for lossy formats such as JPEG; PNG is almost required here (and did I mention that a more advanced (?) user could also extract the code that decodes the content).

## Video Encryption (`EncryptedMediaExtensions` API)

Another way is to provide the images as a video stream (each part could be a frame) protected with DRM. This *may* have some influence in the case of screen grabber depending on OS/hardware support etc, but don't bet on it (even if the [browser support DRM](https://caniuse.com/#search=drm))...

Without DRM it's simply a matter of obtaining the video and use tools such as ffmpeg to extract each frame.

## Watermarking

A widely adopted solution, at least in the field of stock photos, is to watermark each preview and tile. This will level up the game and force the determined user to fire up Photoshop or something similar, and to spend more time than what is considered fun in order to remove them; with variable result.

This may or may not be suitable in your case.

## Value?

Personally, I would not spend the time trying to do this. The efforts put into this will soon enough be worked around.

Depending on the purpose, watermarking tiles/parts (at source) is probably the more efficient solution.

Comment: Maybe I've misundestood the question ([a clarifying OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997286/drawing-parts-of-a-blob-to-html-canvas-without-data-urls-in-javascript#comment78954769_45997286)), but I think they just want to prevent users to cheat in some kind of a reveal-an-image-game, i.e. prevent users to see the full image too early.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I think I'm going to do what you said and scramble the image server-side and then descramble after moving the data to the canvas. That way the image in inspector will be illegible. 
Everyone else told me security holes and flaws I already knew, I just need some low-effort obscurity additions and this was perfect. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can make sure that users can access only allowed content is to give them only this.

Hence you need to process and slice your image on the server and then repass only needed parts to the client.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
We're more trying to eliminate the low-hanging fruit. The nature of being able to view any part of the image means people could just build a auto-click scanner that views each piece and rebuilds the image anyway. Just like snapchat you can't stop people from storing what is displayed.

Hence we just want to eliminate that *incredibly easy* download methods.

Comment: To manipulate image data in Javascript you need to or draw it on the canvas ( like i did here https://codepen.io/valeriavg/pen/VKOWry) or implement your own binary-to-pixel conversion.